# Read csv file with empty lines

Tags: python, csv, break

Analysis software I'm using outputs many groups of results in 1 csv file and separates the groups with 2 empty lines.
I would like to break the results in groups so that I can then analyse them separately.

I'm sure there is a built-in function in python (or one of it's libraries) that does this, I tried this piece of code that I found somewhere but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import csv
results = open('03_12_velocity_y.csv').read().split("\n\n")
# Feed first csv.reader
first_csv = csv.reader(results[0], delimiter=',')
# Feed second csv.reader
second_csv = csv.reader(results[1], delimiter=',')
```

Update:
The original code actually works, but my python skills are pretty limited and I did not implement it properly.
.split(\n\n\n) method does work but the csv.reader is an object and to get the data in a list (or something similar), it needs to iterate through all the rows and write them to the list.
I then used Pandas to remove the header and convert the scientific notated values to float. Code is bellow. Thanks everyone for help.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

# Open the csv file, read it and split it when it encounters 2 empty lines (\n\n\n)
results = open('03_12_velocity_y.csv').read().split('\n\n\n')

# Create csv.reader objects that are used to iterate over rows in a csv file
# Define the output - create an empty multi-dimensional list
output1 = [[],[]]

# Iterate through the rows in the csv file and append the data to the empty list

# Feed first csv.reader
csv_reader1 = csv.reader(results[0].splitlines(), delimiter=',')

for row in csv_reader1:
    output1.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(output1)

# remove first 7 rows of data (the start position of the slice is always included)
df = df.iloc[7:]

# Convert all data from string to float
df = df.astype(float)
```

Comment: Seems like 2 empty lines would be delimited by "\n\n\n" as all lines already end with one "\n".  (unless your description is incorrect).  There are some other issues, but that would be the first thing I would look at.

Comment: I tried \n\n\n and it also doesn't work

Comment: does this work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55809933/how-to-split-a-csv-file-on-blank-rows

Comment: Explain *doesn't seem to work*. That is not a problem statement, only an expression of dissatisfaction. What is the length of `results` after the `open()`  call? If it does not agree with the number of groups you see in the file then the delimiter your code passes to `split()` is wrong. There could be spaces or tabs or carriage returns between the linefeeds. Since we can't see your data, we have to go on your description. And since you're getting unexpected results, the data is clearly a little different from what you think it is. @Gardener already suggested that might be a factor.

Answer (score 0):

TRY this out with your output:

```
import pandas as pd

# csv file name to be read in 
in_csv = 'input.csv'

# get the number of lines of the csv file to be read
number_lines = sum(1 for row in (open(in_csv)))

# size of rows of data to write to the csv, 
# you can change the row size according to your need
rowsize = 500

# start looping through data writing it to a new file for each set
for i in range(1,number_lines,rowsize):
    df = pd.read_csv(in_csv,
         header=None,
         nrows = rowsize,#number of rows to read at each loop
         skiprows = i)#skip rows that have been read

     #csv to write data to a new file with indexed name. input_1.csv etc.
     out_csv = 'input' + str(i) + '.csv'

df.to_csv(out_csv,
    index=False,
    header=False,
    mode='a', #append data to csv file
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If your row counts are inconsistent across groups, you'll need a little state machine to check when you're between groups and do something with the last group.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv


def write_group(group, i):
    with open(f"group_{i}.csv", "w", newline="") as out_f:
        csv.writer(out_f).writerows(group)


with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    group_i = 1
    group = []
    last_row = []
    for row in reader:
        if row == [] and last_row == [] and group != []:
            write_group(group, group_i)
            group = []
            group_i += 1
            continue

        if row == []:
            last_row = row
            continue

        group.append(row)
        last_row = row

# flush remaining group
if group != []:
    write_group(group, group_i)
```

I mocked up this sample CSV:

```
g1r1c1,g1r1c2,g1r1c3
g1r2c1,g1r2c2,g1r2c3
g1r3c1,g1r3c2,g1r3c3


g2r1c1,g2r1c2,g2r1c3
g2r2c1,g2r2c2,g2r2c3


g3r1c1,g3r1c2,g3r1c3
g3r2c1,g3r2c2,g3r2c3
g3r3c1,g3r3c2,g3r3c3
g3r4c1,g3r4c2,g3r4c3
g3r5c1,g3r5c2,g3r5c3
```

And when I run the program above I get three CSV files:

**group_1.csv**

```
g1r1c1,g1r1c2,g1r1c3
g1r2c1,g1r2c2,g1r2c3
g1r3c1,g1r3c2,g1r3c3
```

**group_2.csv**

```
g2r1c1,g2r1c2,g2r1c3
g2r2c1,g2r2c2,g2r2c3
```

**group_3.csv**

```
g3r1c1,g3r1c2,g3r1c3
g3r2c1,g3r2c2,g3r2c3
g3r3c1,g3r3c2,g3r3c3
g3r4c1,g3r4c2,g3r4c3
g3r5c1,g3r5c2,g3r5c3
```

Answer (score 0):

If your row counts are consistent, you can do this with fairly vanilla Python or using the Pandas library.

### Vanilla Python

- Define your group size and the size of the break (in "rows") between groups.
- Loop over all the rows adding each row to a group accumulator.
- When the group accumulator reaches the pre-defined group size, do something with it, reset the accumulator, and then skip break-size rows.

Here, I'm writing each group to its own numbered file:

```py
import csv

group_sz = 5
break_sz = 2


def write_group(group, i):
    with open(f"group_{i}.csv", "w", newline="") as f_out:
        csv.writer(f_out).writerows(group)


with open("input.csv", newline="") as f_in:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)

    group_i = 1
    group = []
    for row in reader:
        group.append(row)

        if len(group) == group_sz:
            write_group(group, group_i)

            group_i += 1
            group = []

            for _ in range(break_sz):
                try:
                    next(reader)
                except StopIteration:  # gracefully ignore an expected StopIteration (at the end of the file)
                    break
```

**group_1.csv**

```
g1r1c1,g1r1c2,g1r1c3
g1r2c1,g1r2c2,g1r2c3
g1r3c1,g1r3c2,g1r3c3
g1r4c1,g1r4c2,g1r4c3
g1r5c1,g1r5c2,g1r5c3
```

### With Pandas

I'm new to Pandas, and learning this as I go, but it looks like Pandas will automatically trim blank rows/records from a chunk of data[^1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-chunking).

With that in mind, all you need to do is specify the size of your group, and tell Pandas to read your CSV file in "iterator mode", where you can ask for a chunk (your group size) of records at a time:

```py
import pandas as pd

group_sz = 5

with pd.read_csv("input.csv", header=None, iterator=True) as reader:
    i = 1
    while True:
        try:
            df = reader.get_chunk(group_sz)
        except StopIteration:
            break

        df.to_csv(f"group_{i}.csv")
        i += 1
```

Pandas add an "ID" column and default header when it writes out the CSV:

**group_1.csv**

```
,0,1,2
0,g1r1c1,g1r1c2,g1r1c3
1,g1r2c1,g1r2c2,g1r2c3
2,g1r3c1,g1r3c2,g1r3c3
3,g1r4c1,g1r4c2,g1r4c3
4,g1r5c1,g1r5c2,g1r5c3
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the question with the last details that answer my question.

Comment: Why not moving here (as part of the answer) the "last details that answer [your] question" instead of having the answer inside your question? That's not a good practice in Stack Overflow.