# How to pull data from a text file into sentences defined as rows of data in between blank rows?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, data-mining

Data is located in a text file, and I want to group the data inside it into sentences. Definition of a sentence is all the rows one after another with at least 1 character in each row. There are blank rows in between the rows with data and so I want the blank rows to mark the beginning and end of a sentence. Is there a way to do this with list comprehension?

Example from text file. Data would look like this:

```
This is the
first sentence.

This is a really long sentence
and it just keeps going across many
rows there will not necessarily be 
punctuation
or consistency in word length
the only difference in ending sentence
is the next row will be blank

here would be the third sentence
as 
you see
the blanks between rows of data 
help define what a sentence is

this would be sentence 4
i want to pull data
from text file
as such (in sentences) 
where sentences are defined with
blank records in between

this would be sentence 5 since blank row above it
and continues but ends because blank row(s) below it
```

Comment: You may wish to provide a sample from your text file.

Comment: `sentences = entire_file_as_string.split('\n\n')` should work

Comment: thank you all for the comments so far; I added example text to my posting and I will try what you mentioned @ADdV. Will let you know in a bit if that worked for me.

Comment: @mrkrieger your response of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852712/python-split-on-empty-new-line is the correct solution to my question; thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the whole file as a single string with `file_as_string = file_object.read()`. As you want to split this string on an empty line, that's equivalent to splitting on two subsequent newline characters, so we can do `sentences = file_as_string.split("\n\n")`. Finally, you might want to remove the line breaks that are still present in the middle of the sentences. You can do that with a list comprehension, replacing newlines with nothing: `sentences = [s.replace('\n', '') for s in sentences]`

In total that gives:

```
file_as_string = file_object.read()
sentences = file_as_string.split("\n\n")
sentences = [s.replace('\n', '') for s in sentences]
```

Comment: @roadrunner66 Both the question and the example indicate that "blank rows to mark the beginning and end of a sentence". The example also includes "there will not necessarily be punctuation". I read that as the format of the data as-is, not the format of the desired result, but if asker clarifies otherwise I'll change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex split very effectively for this.

If you want to split only by double spaces, use:

```
^[ \t]*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hAaYZd/2/)

In Python, you can do:

```
import re   

with open(fn) as f_in:
    sentencences=re.split(r'\r?\n^[ \t]*$', f_in.read(), flags=re.M)
```

If you want to remove the individual `\n` of the text:

```
with open(fn) as f_in:
    sentencences=[re.sub(r'[ \t]*(?:\r?\n){1,}', ' ', s) 
         for s in re.split(r'\r?\n^[ \t]*$', f_in.read(), flags=re.M)]
```