# Get value after blank line

Tags: python

How to get a value from a file and save it into two lists, separated by a blank line?

My file is like:

```
Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
Totam temporibus, provident qui ullam laudantium libero.

Lorem, ipsum
```

My goal is to achieve two lists:

```
text = ['Lorem,', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', 'consectetur', 'adipisicing', 'elit.', 'Totam', 'temporibus,', 'provident', 'qui', 'ullam', 'laudantium', 'libero.']
```

```
formula = ['Lorem,', 'ipsum']
```

My current code, which gives me wrong solution:

```
file = open('file.txt', 'r')
    lines = file.readlines()

    formula = []
    data = []

    for line in lines:
        if '\n' in line:
            continue
            formula.append(line.strip())
        else:
            data.append(line.strip())

    print('formula', pattern, 'data', data)
    file.close()
```

Comment: What exactly is your question about this? Is there a particular problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: I don't understand what the example text has to do with the question. There is no blank line in it.

Comment: You should not have `continue` before an executable line of code.

Comment: Are you asking this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852712/python-split-on-empty-new-line

Comment: Taking your question literally, the desired result can be achieved like this: `text, formula = [x.split() for x in file.read().strip().split('\n\n')]`. However, I doubt your real input file looks like the example you've shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do

but I guess you want to tokenize your text and then strip each token if that so
here what you could do

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    tokens = f.read().split(" ")

tokens = [item.strip() for item in data]
```

EDIT

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.read().split("\n")
    Flag = False
    FirstPart = [] 
    LastPart = []
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) == 0:
            Flag = True
        if not Flag:
            FirstPart.append(line)
        else:
            LastPart.append(line)
```

Comment: I want to split text from the file into two lists. The first list contains all text up to the blank line. The second list contains text after the blank line.

Comment: the code updated, hopefully now helps!